# Caffe 2 Install fails on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, eigen, pytorch, caffe2

It's been a fairly treacherous journey with dozens of error messages. I am installing Caffe 2 from source onto a Windows 10 machine with an Nvidia GPU. I have installed VS2017 Community Edition (CE), CUDA 9.2 and cuDNN. I am able to build the CUDA sample `.sln` files into `.exe`'s and run the `.exe`'s successfully.

Presently, I am trying to install Caffe 2. Naturally, there's an error on this step as well. Like my previous issues, I have tried Googling this error. Unfortunately, I am unable to find others with the same issue and consequently cannot find hints for a solution.

According to the Caffe 2 installation instrucitons at: https://caffe2.ai/docs/getting-started.html?platform=windows&configuration=compile:

```
1. git clone --recursive https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git
2. build_windows.bat from the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017
```

on step 2., I get the following error:

```
       "C:\Users\andcy\pytorch\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
       "C:\Users\andcy\pytorch\build\caffe2\caffe2.vcxproj" (default target) (13) ->
       (ClCompile target) ->
         c:\users\andcy\pytorch\third_party\eigen\eigen\src\core\products\generalblockpanelkernel.h(1902): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler. [C:\Users\andcy\pytorch\build\caffe2\caffe2.vcxproj]
         cl : Command line error D8040: error creating or communicating with child process [C:\Users\andcy\pytorch\build\caffe2\caffe2.vcxproj]

    3282 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:05:11.58
"Caffe2 building failed"

C:\Users\andcy\pytorch\scripts>
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to resolve this issue? I've been trying to install Caffe 2 on my local machine for about a week.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the official troubleshooting section of Caffe2,

> Until NVIDIA updates CUDA to support VS 17, you’re going to have to install VS 15 and try again.

So, you need to install Visual Studio 15 to install Caffe2 on Windows 10. The troubleshooting section can be found at [Install Caffe2 on Windows](https://caffe2.ai/docs/getting-started.html?platform=windows&configuration=compile)